# Split documentation from SO

Tags: discussion, documentation

It seems to me that splitting out documentation onto its own SE site and making it have its own rep would solve a lot of problems. I don't really care about documentation. I frankly don't see the point. What bothers me is the inflation of rep on SO for users who seem to have no idea how SO works. This would easily be solved by splitting documentation out of SO.

I don't really see why documentation was tied to SO that closely in the first place. Its clearly meant to be different from our usual Q&A. But mixing two different systems with very different approaches gets only the worst of everything.

Currently, documentation can not develop its own sense of what should belong there. The community has no way to figure out what is appropriate for documentation and what not. The learning process that every other SE site goes through does not exist for documentation - and thats because its tied to SO rep. The stakes are much higher and mistakes negatively impact SO. That has not been the issue with any other new SE site.

Documentation inflates rep. There is way too much rep given for it. This wouldn't be a problem if it wasn't tied to SO. Priviliages could be balanced for what ever rep levels are appropriate for documentation if it was split out.

Inflating rep also has a negative impact on job searches and possibly even SO careers. If rep doesn't mean anything anymore, that hurts. Again no problem if documentation rep was split out.

Splitting it out would also mean the team can take a more relaxed approach to finding fair and good balancing for documentation rep. Because rep is important on SO, and gettingit without understanding SOs culture will negatively impact SO in the long run. If rep was split out, at least SO wouldn't be hurt.

On SO, we have Community Wiki for answers that are edited by multiple people - to avoid piling up rep. On documentation, the exact opposite happens - free rep for everyone. This alone should be enough to see that there is a huge philosophical difference between SO and documentation - and that it should be kept seperate.

I could just hop on the bandwagon and try to inflate my rep by gaming doc. But to be honest thats not my style. I want to gain my feathers fair and square. SO always had a strong culture and focused on quality, but I fear this might be over soon if this trend continues.